# In interface design, which icon is best suited to represent "icon"?

Tags: website-design, icon, interface-design, button

I'm building an interface for users to create a web page.  The user clicks a button to choose an icon from an array of icons to be used on their page.

I have always been stumped as to which icon is best suited for use on the "choose icon" button, which itself is simply an icon on a grey background.

My closest icon approximations have always either been an (eye) or the letter (i) in icon form.

Is there a standard icon for "icon"?

Comment: What's the purpose behind choosing an icon?

Answer (score 2):

This question on [ux.stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13960/an-icon-to-represent-all-icons) lead to the conclusion that there simply *is not a standard icon to represent all icons*.

I would agree. Your only course of action here is to consider what your "icon of icons" is actually trying to represent.

If for instance it's intended to be on a form where a user can select an icon, then the "pencil" icon might do the trick. Otherwise think outside the box and use the WORD "icon", or perhaps create your own icon with "icon" written on it (Concept follows... not a masterpiece!)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something that expands to present the user with multiple choices, so it would make sense to go for a dropdown, fold-out or grid icon.

Go to the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com), search these and see what works with your interface:

- expand
- drop down
- fold out
- grid view
- add/insert

Or just do this:
[image]

I would move away from the 'icon-to-represent-multiple-icons' idea. There is probably no such thing.